# Cannot write to a file on Android device

Tags: android, csv, path

I am trying to use CSVWriter to write to a file for my android project.

As part of my folder structure I have created a folder called `myData` and within that have a CSV file called `results.csv`

```
String csvpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
CSVWriter csvw = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvpath+"/myData/results.csv"));
```

However I get the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myData/results.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have also added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I get the correct path for this file?

Comment: Did you require the permission to write?

Comment: The READ permission is optional - WRITE includes it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have to create the myData Folder Otherwise it will throws the exception.

```
    File dir=new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyDate");
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    CSVWriter csvw = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/results.csv"));
```

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Just tried it, it is now working. Thank you for this!